# C++ Equality checking in maps from pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, identity, equality

```
SOME_MAP<Foo*, int> map = SOME_MAP<Foo*, int>();
Foo *a = new Foo(42);
Foo *b = new Foo(42);

map[a] = 42;
cout << map[b] << endl; // Should print 42 if *a == *b.
```

Is there some map class in stl or some common library that offers a map that allows me to store pointers, but does the internal equality checking --and possibly hashing too-- using operators on the objects pointed to, rather than the pointers themselves?

I can't store the object directly in the map since the map's type parameter has to be an abstract super class.

Comment: Did you try passing a custom compare to the `map` (via template argument)? I bet you didn't. Here's the [documentation for `std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)...it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible for all associative containers in the STL. For the sorted and unsorted.

Sorted

- [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)
- [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)
- [std::multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)
- [std::multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Unsorted

- [std::unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)
- [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)
- [std::unordered_multiset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset)
- [std::unordered_multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)

Please click on the link to get more information. What you will also learn there is that all ordered associative container have a template parameter "Compare" and the unordered associative container have a "KeyEqual" template parameter.

You can simply define a simple functor and hand this in as template parameter.

Let's take your map as example. We will define a functor for comparison:

```
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const Foo* f1, const Foo* f2) { return f1->value < f2->value; }
};
```

and can then write an overall example like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map> 

struct Foo {
    Foo(int v) : value(v) {};
    int value{};
};

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const Foo* f1, const Foo* f2) { return f1->value < f2->value; }
};

int main() {
    Foo *a = new Foo(42);
    Foo *b = new Foo(42);
    
    std::map<Foo *, int, Compare>  myMap{};
    
    myMap[a] = 10;
    std::cout << myMap[b] << '\n' << "size: "  << myMap.size() << '\n';
}
```

In your case, normally by using the `std::map`s index operator `[]` a new node for "Foo +b" would be inserted.

But not here, because the "Compare" functor will find out that an element with such properties alreay exists.

Rund the program and you will see that the size at the end is still 1. So, only one element in the `std::map`

For the unordered associative containers, you would need a different functor, like for example:

```
struct KeyEqual{
    bool operator()(const Foo* f1, const Foo* f2) { return f1->value == f2->value; }
};
```